# How to calculate and display circuits, closed paths, simple paths, cycles ... of edges (with a specific length)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I'd like to know that how can I find circuit(basic), simple path, closed path of these edges:

Example:

```
V={V, R, F, P, W}
E={(V, R), (R, V), (R, F), (F, V), (V, W), (W, V), (W, P), (P, F)}
```

Please mention all the steps as straight forward as possible. How can I find out that how many Circuits, cycles, closed paths, simple paths, ... with a specific length does it have?(and display the edges of that circuit, cycle, closed path, simple path ...)

For example: display circuits of 2 edges? answer should be: `{(V, R), (R, V)}, {(V, W), (V, W)}`

Thanks

Comment: Combinatorica would have been the method of choice in the past, but `Graph[]` is now built in. Have you looked at its documentation?

Comment: I have just graphed it, but how to find the circuit, simple path, closed path...?

Comment: Please show what you tried. When you are asking for help, it is best to try to meet us halfway. Include code to construct the graph. Define the concepts you want computed. Do search the documentation before asking, try the functions you find, and ask about the _specific_ problems you encountered when trying to use them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a graph edge in Mathematica is not defined by parentheses. You can use the command `DirectedEdge[u,v]` for an edge from the vertex u to another vertex v. Or you can use the command `Rule[u,v]`. For a two sided edge you can use `TwoWayRule[u,v]`, for an undirected edge you can use `UndirectedEdge[u,v]`. Or you can use the keyboard, type u, then "*Esc*" key, then type `ue` (abbreviation of **u**ndirected **e**dge), then press "*Esc*" key again. For directed edge use `de` instead of `ue`, or you can just type `u->v`. I also prefer to not use Capital letters for names of objects unless I really need and I'm sure it is not reserved for anything. So I changed your vertices names to small letters as well. To ask Mathematica to find a cycle in your graph just use the commend `FindCycle[]` and put name of your graph inside the brackets. To restrict it to cycles of a fixed length such as 2, just add the option `{2}` (without eyebrows, it will search for cycles with length at most equal to 2). Then Mathematica gives you only one cycle of interest. If you want to receive a list containing all of such cycles, add the option `All`. To ask Mathematica to highlight the cycle or any subgraph of your graph, just use the command `Highlight` and give names of your graph and the subgraph as its arguments. In below you can see how I did things I mentioned above on your graph.

```
vertices={v,r,f,p,w};
edges={DirectedEdge[v,r],DirectedEdge[r,v],DirectedEdge[r,f],DirectedEdge[f,v],DirectedEdge[v,w],DirectedEdge[w,v],DirectedEdge[w,p],DirectedEdge[p,f]};
graph=Graph[vertices,edges]
subgraph=FindCycle[graph,{2}]
HighlightGraph[graph,subgraph]
subgraphList=FindCycle[graph,{2},All]
```

To see the results in Mathematica itself, you can look at the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a directed graph in which there's an edge connecting each vertex pair in a list, it's easy to convert the vertex list to edges (to make undirected edges, use `UndirectedEdge`). Use the list of edges to make a graph.

```
edges = DirectedEdge[##] & @@@ {{V,R}, {R,V}, {R,F}, {F,V}, {V,W}, {W,V}, {W,P}, {P,F}};
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels->Automatic, ImageSize->Small]
```

[image: graph from list of edges]

Get vertex and edge lists from the graph with `VertexList[g]` and `EdgeList[g]`.

Finding circuits of 2 edges is simple. Highlight the list of cycles on the graph with [HighlightGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html).  Use [Grid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)
 and [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html)
 to arrange the highlighted graphs into rows and columns, a technique we'll use later to display larger numbers of graphs.

```
edgeList = Sort@FindCycle[g, {2}, All]
```

> [image: circuits of 2 edges]

```
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g, #] &/@ edgeList, UpTo[3]], Frame->All]
```

[image: graph of cycles]

Find and display ***all*** cycles in the graph with `FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]`.

```
edgeList = FindCycle[g, Infinity, All];
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g, #] &/@ edgeList, UpTo[3]], Frame->All]
```

[image: all cycles for a graph]

Some graph manipulation functions, such as [FindHamiltonianPath](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html) return a list of vertices, but we need a list of directed edges to display a highlighted graph. For example, to convert the `FindHamiltonianPath` vertex list into pairs of directed edges, use `DirectedEdge[##] &@@@ Subsequences[FindHamiltonianPath[g], {2}]`.

```
edgeList = DirectedEdge[##] &@@@ Subsequences[FindHamiltonianPath[g], {2}];
HighlightGraph[g, edgeList], ImageSize->Small]
```

[image: Hamiltonian path]

[FindPath](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath.html) returns lists of vertices, so we'll need to convert them to lists of edges following the Hamiltonian path example. `FindPath` can locate all simple paths between two vertices. For example, to find paths from vertex *R* to vertex *P*, use `FindPath[g,R,P,Infinity,All]`.

```
edgeList = DirectedEdge[##] &@@@ Subsequences[#,{2}] &/@ FindPath[g,R,P,Infinity,All];
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g, #] &/@ edgeList, UpTo[3]], Frame->All]
```

[image: paths between two vertices]

We can use the same method to find ***all*** simple paths between ***all*** edges, but first we need a list of each pair of vertices. Make the list with `Sort@Permutations[VertexList[g], {2}]`. Use the list of vertex pairs to make a grid of graphs that displays all paths between every pair of vertices (large grid of 28 graphs omitted).

```
edgeList = DirectedEdge[##] &@@@ Subsequences[#, {2}]
  &/@Flatten[FindPath[g, ##, Infinity, All]
  &@@@Sort@Permutations[VertexList[g], {2}], 1];
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g, #] &/@ edgeList, UpTo[3]], Frame->All]
```

Using the `edgeList`, it's easy to choose only the paths of given length. For example, here's how to display all the paths with 4 edges:

```
Grid[Partition[HighlightGraph[g,#] &/@ Select[edgeList, Length[#]==4&], UpTo[3]], Frame->All]
```

[image: paths with 4 edges]

We can use `edgeList` to make a summary of the number of edges in the 28 paths:

```
pathList = KeySort@GroupBy[edgeList,Length];
TableForm[Transpose[{Keys[pathList],Length/@Values[pathList]}],
  TableHeadings->{None,{"edges","number of paths"}}]
```

> ```
> edges  number of paths
> 1      8
> 2      9
> 3      8
> 4      3
> ```